# WordPress admin webfonts (dashicons) go to blank squares after inactivity (random)

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

I'm using the new WordPress 3.8 and I've noticed that when I leave the admin page open in a tab, and return later, I'm getting a random thing happening with the dashicon fonts used for the menu icons.

They all turn to squares, rather than the appropriate dashicon. Its as if the connection to the server that hosts the webfonts has been temporarily lost.

Interestingly, just moving my mouse over the sidebar area makes the squares transform into their appropriate dashicon font symbol.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I have seen it happen on other sites that use icon fonts as well. Perhaps a browser (Chrome) bug?

Comment: Can confirm that in Chrome.

Comment: This is interesting: http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/